# TortoiseSVN SQL scripts automation

Tags: sql, sql-server, tortoisesvn

I would like to automatically execute committed under TortoiseSVN SQL scripts (list of commited files already exist).

As I see it:

When Update command is executed execute batch file which does the following:

1. get list of added/modified *.sql files (maybe copy them to some temp directory)
2. execute those files using sqlcmd (if files were copied to a separate directory then this can be done using `for %f in (c:\MySQLScripts\*.sql) do sqlcmd -i %f`)

Is there a solution for such flow (of any other which targets to the same goal)?

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago we attempted to do what you're proposing, and found that co-ordinating script execution so that all dependencies (e.g., foreign keys) were resolved was very complicated, if not impossible.

We settled on using RedGate SQL Source Control (integrates with Subversion, like TortoiseSVN) and SQL Compare for deploying from source control.  You should take a look: http://www.red-gate.com/.

An alternate approach is to use the Management Studio "Generate Scripts" functionality (right-click on database in object explorer, tasks -> Generate Scripts). It'll create a "master script" that contains all database objects. You can source control this script, and execute it using sqlcmd.  I can't speak to how well this utility manages the dependencies I refer to above.